# Why there're different host headers when making requests in Next.js?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, http-headers, next.js, http-host

I host my Next.js app on Amazon Web Services in Elastic Beanstalk inside a docker container. I recently noticed by printing `req.host` from Express.js that whenever a request is sent to `/_next*` route the host is `myid.elasticebeanstalk.com`. In all other requests (e.g. for the actual page or request to API server) the host is `example.com` both client-side and server-side (supposing that my app is hosted at that address).

I'm wondering why is it that way? How can I set the host header even to `/_next*` routes to be `example.com`? I suspect that sometime this could result in SSL error because the host will not be correct.

The elastic beanstalk config is single instance. The DNS records are configures in AWS Route 53. The host header with `myid.elasticebeanstalk.com` appears in serverside requests only. `example.com` is a CNAME, **not** an alias. The logs are made inside the docker container. In general the SSL certificate is supplied by AWS in Cloudfront I think.

**EDIT:** it looks like the hostname should be set in the host operating system in Elastic Beanstalk which should be Linux. This [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html) explains this.

Comment: Could you provide some more information about your Elastic Beanstalk configuration? Is this a single instance or load-balanced environment?
Where did you configure a DNS record for example.com to point at myid.elasticbeanstalk.com? Could you provide some more general info for a better overview of your scenario?

Comment: I added the answers to your questions in the OP.

Comment: example.com is a CNAME-Record or an alias record pointing at myid.elasticbeanstalk.com? "appears in serverside requests only" means that you are logging the host header in the docker container?
As you are writing about SSL... Where do you terminate the SSL connection? Do you currently use SSL or do you plan to use it and are concerned about the wrong host headers being logged?

Comment: I added the answers to your questions in the OP. Regarding the SSL  currently there're no issues but I just want to understand why some requests have different hosts.

Comment: Thanks! What I basically try to understand here is how many services / servers are between your client and the nextjs backend in order to figure out which component is setting the host header you are logging.

Comment: try request.headers.host instead

Answer (score 1):

To set custom HTTP headers you can use the headers key in next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/about',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'x-custom-header',
            value: 'my custom header value',
          },
          {
            key: 'x-another-custom-header',
            value: 'my other custom header value',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

`headers` is an async function that expects an array to be returned holding objects with `source` and `headers` properties:

`source` is the incoming request path pattern.

`headers` is an array of header objects with the `key` and `value` properties.